# Please help me! How do I create new projects on a new account?

Tags: smtp, google-cloud-platform, gmail, resources

I really need someone who knows how to set up new projects in Google Cloud inside and out for a definitive answer. I'm setting up a new project in Google Cloud so that I can Send Emails in WordPress using the Gmail SMTP Server.

Every time I try to create any new project, I get a generic error message telling me that I need to select a parent organization or location.

Error message states:

You don’t have the required resource manager project create permission to create projects in this location.

Since I'm not able to create this new project, I'm also not able to complete the Gmail SMTP Server Setup.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was going to post a question there but Super User is for computer enthusiasts if you have a question about …

    computer hardware,
    computer software, or
    personal and home computer networking

Comment: @MichaelHampton i think last one lol

Comment: I don't this falls under the home computer networking category... there's others here who've asked similar questions to the one I posted.

Comment: Hello @MarciaTurley. Does any of the below answers [helped you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

**You're not able to create a new project because of lack of permissions.**

Please have a look at the documentation [Creating a project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project):

> To create a project, you must have the
> `resourcemanager.projects.create` permission. This permission is
> included in the Project Creator `roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator role`, which is granted by default to the entire domain of a new
> organization and to free trial users. For information on how to grant
> individuals the role and limit organization-wide access, see the
> [Managing Default Organization Roles](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/default-access-control) page.

**To solve this issue** add this role at the Organization level.

---

**Unfortunately, you won't be able to send email directly from your VM.**

Please have a look on the documentation [Sending email from an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail):

> Due to the risk of abuse, connections to destination TCP Port 25 are [always blocke](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic)d when the destination is external to your VPC network. This includes using SMTP relay with Google Workspace.

As a result, port 25, which is used by [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol), is blocked:

> Most [mailbox providers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailbox_Provider) still allow submission on traditional port 25. The MSA delivers the mail to its mail transfer agent ([mail transfer agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_transfer_agent), MTA).

As a workaround, **to send emails you should follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail#choosing_an_email_service_to_use)** and use email relays like [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid), [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun) or [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailjet) or your Google Workspace domain.

Comment: Hello @MarciaTurley. Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to create projects you need **resourcemanager.projects.create** permission or **roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator** role.
Both can be granted by your organization admin like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107230/cant-create-a-new-project-on-google-cloud-console-you-must-select-a-parent-or).
To find out who is your Organization Administrator, open https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=YOUR_PROJECT_NAME

---

As mentioned by @Serhii, port 25 is blocked and cannot be opened by adding a firewall rule.
You can set up your email server to use port 587 or 465 as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#using_standard_email_ports).
Alternatively, you can send your emails through [Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600).